# XSS between HTTP and HTTPS versions of the same domain

Tags: jquery, iframe, https, xss

What I'm trying to accomplish is an inline login using ajax that does the following:

1. Login link is displayed on an unsecured HTTP page, lets say "http://www.somedomain.com/somepage/" **No login info is collected here**
2. When clicked the login link creates an iframe with a src pointing to "https://www.somedomain.com/rest_api/values/"  **This is where the login form is first displayed, via HTTPS**
3. Within the new iframe popup, the user is presented a login form which itself is secure having been loaded via HTTPS, user fills in form and clicks continue which posts back to itself.
4. Assuming user is logged in successfully a jquery call is made to a script accessible via `window.parent.document` which updates the original page with the current user widget, and then calls for the iframe to be destroyed.

This works great when I force the iframe to use the same domain and protocol, but as soon as I come in on HTTP and force the IFRAME to load the login script with HTTPS, I get the dreaded "Permission denied to access property 'document'" error in Firebug after a successful login.

I understand that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header needs to be set, so it's dynamically set to use the HTTPS version of what ever domain the page is being requested under, and I've verified this in the Header Response in Firebug on the original page request.

So why am I still getting the error, the response header shows:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.somedomain.com
```

so is there something else I need to set, or is the problem possibly somewhere else?

Thanks for any help!

---

EDIT: Updated above to point out that I am not stupid and that the login form is indeed loaded securely ;)

Comment: At step 1, you've already failed.  The login page must be served over HTTPS, or you will have very little security

Comment: @SLaks  Maybe I wasn't clear, when you click login to create the IFRAME, you aren't filling anything in yet, all you're doing is launching the script that creates the IFRAME, and sets the src to load the login form within it via HTTPS.  So it is indeed secure.

Comment: @SLaks Am i misinterpreting? The way i read it is the login form is being presented in an iFrame pointing to an https domain. so, the login form itself is on https, it just can't talk to the parent page because it is of a different origin (not https)

Comment: @SLaks It might've been a bit confusing the way I described it, the iframe indeed loads the login form via HTTPS dispite the parent window being loaded via HTTP.  The Login form having been loaded via HTTPS and the eventual form submission are all completed within the IFRAME and via HTTPS, so unless I'm missing something all communications are secured.  The problem occurs on the successful login, the success page simply loads a page that does an immediate jquery call to populate the parent page with a new user widget, and then destroy the iframe. Make sense?

Comment: @oucil: That doesn't help at all.  The attacker modifies the original page to load `https://evil.com/login-stealer` in the iframe, and the user is none the wiser.  Users should be (but probably aren't) trained to only enter their passwords if they see https in the address bar.

Comment: @SLaks I'm unsure of how this is possible unless the clients computer was already compromised, with a Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in place the browser shouldn't allow any adjustments to the DOM from scripts that don't belong to the current or specified origins, that's the whole point isn't it?  Can you point me to any resources that describe the type of attack you believe this would leave me open to?

Comment: @KevinB You read it correct, the domains are the exact same, only the protocol is different, HTTP vs. HTTPS

Comment: @oucil: An MITM attacker can modify the JS on the original page to do whatever he wants, bypassing or replacing the iframe & your HTTPS stuff entirely.

Comment: @SLaks Wouldn't they just as easily be able to replace a regular href to a login page by that logic, spoofing the login page to look like ours?  From what I understand, without getting too technical, the only way to protect against MITM is to force SSL end to end, no exceptions, which simply isn't a realistic solution.  I understand the implication of not displaying the lock to a user, this option is more of a convenience, whilst still providing an expected level of protection.  I was also going to including a link to a standalone login page if they still didn't trust the option.

Comment: @oucil: As you mentioned, the difference is whether the user sees the lock icon _when they enter their credentials_.  Hopefully, they'll check after clicking the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the "should I / shouldn't I" issue raised above by @SLaks, which is valid, but a question that any site needs to weigh for itself... the technical problem I was facing was this, the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` *on it's own* was not enough, it needs to be set along with the following:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
```

I'm not positive if the first one is necessary for the exact scenario I was describing since the jquery was simply run *after* a successful POST rather than a POST or GET call itself, but it's there for your reference, and because I needed it for other use cases for our site.

The second one `...Allow-Headers` was the kicker though, since the headers included `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` because it was originally called using an *XMLHttpRequest* out of jquery, specifically *.ajax()*.

With all three in place, I've had no problems since.  Hope this helps others in the same situation!

---

EDIT: Fooled myself, the HTTPS to HTTP still didn't work, and from the remaining day I spent still trying to figure this out, it's become obvious that it won't despite the fact it should.

So the end solution was, Load the login page via HTTPS, submit via HTTPS, and upon successful login, redirect to HTTP to send a call back to the parent to remove the login iframe.